# When does sup and function commute?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

For $f,g$ real-valued functions, $f$ weakly increasing and continuous, $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, can we say
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\in A}f(g(x))=f(\sup_{x\in A}g(x))
\end{align*}

I ask because I notice in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) the likelihood ratio test statistic is written as the difference between the log of sups, while in class notes I see it written as the difference in sup of logs.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857360/supremum-can-be-move-to-inside-function-when-function-is-strictly-increasing

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice#Morphisms_of_complete_lattices

Comment: You'll need $A$ to be an interval too.

Comment: @Paul, Sorry but I think with the assumption I made of $f$ increasing, your counterexample doesn't work! $\sup (x \circ 1-x)=1=x \circ \sup 1-x$

Comment: Oop, sorry, somehow I overlooked the "f increasing" feature. I'll delete my remarks.

Comment: You need that $\sup A \in A$, since otherwise how is $f(\sup A)$ defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality is true.

Let $s = \sup \limits_{x \in A} g(x)$. Then for $x \in A$ we have $g(x) \leqslant s$ so $f(g(x)) \leqslant f(s)$, which means that $f(s)$ is an upper bound of the set $\{ f(g(x)) : x \in A \}$. It remains to show that it is the least such bound.

Take any $\varepsilon > 0$. By continuity of $f$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that $f(s) - \varepsilon < f(y) < f(s) + \varepsilon$ whenever $|y-s| < \delta$. Since $s-\delta < s$, there is $x \in A$ such that $s-\delta < g(x)$ and of course $g(x) \leqslant s$, hence $|g(x) - s| < \delta$. Then we get $f(s) - \varepsilon < f(g(x))$, so $f(s) - \varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $\{ f(g(x)) : x \in A \}$, QED.

Comment: Thank you!! This makes sense